# dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: not executed

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

When I call **`dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`** to dismiss a `UIViewController` the completion block is never executed when the corresponding view is in the middle of being animated onto the screen (using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`).

The `UIViewController` does not even dissappear. It is like `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is being ignored.

The following code is a simplified code example because the original is much bigger. The code I have given below simulates a use-case where a network communication error might trigger a view to popup whilst another view is also being popped-up at the same time..

Code example:

```
NSLog(@"Presenting view");

[self presentViewController:changeLocationViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"View done presenting");
}];

NSLog(@"Dismissing view");

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
    NSLog(@"View done dismissing");
}];
```

Log output is:

> 2013-08-28 16:14:12.162 [1708:c07] Presenting view
>   2013-08-28 16:14:12.178 [1708:c07] Dismissing view
>   2013-08-28 16:14:12.583 [1708:c07] View done presenting

Does anyone know how to dismiss the `UIViewController` in these circumstances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of `UIViewController` is it? Have you subclassed it yourself or is it a third-party?

Comment: It is a subclassed UIViewController. But nothing extraordinary. It just shows some text and a button

Comment: Show the code that you wrote to dismiss it, don't just name the method. Maybe there is an error there...

Comment: Is it really being ignored? Have you set breakpoints to check to see if it is being called?

Comment: I have added code to the original post to illustrate. @CaptJak I did set breakpoints, it steps through as normal

Comment: My guess is you have to wait for the view controller to be presented before you can dismiss it.

Comment: @Scott might be right... You can't dismiss something that isn't there. If you check your log you see that it tries to dismiss before it gets presented. Why are your presenting and dismissing the same view in a single method? I think you got your code laid out wrong. What are you trying to do?

Comment: it actually is a simplified code example because the original is much bigger. The code I have given simulates a use-case where a network communication error might trigger a view to popup whilst another view is also being popped-up at the same time

Comment: @CaptJak But maybe you are right, the view isn't there yet so I can't dismiss it. Might I be able to 'cancel' it then, i.s.o. dismissing?

Comment: Why don't you just check (whatever you are checking...) before presenting? Why present-cancel? Less chance of error and crashing that way.

Comment: I might indeed end up like that. I was hoping for a possibility to dismiss or cancel the view as that would be much easier for my current code

Comment: You can't "cancel" the presentation of a view controller while the presentation is in progress. You'll probably want to use a different kind of modal view that's a little more responsive, and doesn't immediately take up the whole screen just because it's not able to communicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this code snippet isn't working is because the completion block in these methods are executed at a later time after the animations have completed.  You can see this in your logs: "Dismissing view" happens before "View done presenting".  Try this instead:

```
NSLog(@"Presenting view");

[self presentViewController:changeLocationViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"View done presenting");
    NSLog(@"Dismissing view");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"View done dismissing");
    }];
}];
```

EDIT:

If you need to make sure the view is dismissed when the network error happens, try setting a boolean instance variable called `networkErrorFound`.

When you finish the network connection, set this to `YES` if an error happens.  Then use this code:

```
[self presentViewController:changeLocationViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"View done presenting");
    NSLog(@"Dismissing view");

    if (self.networkErrorFound) {
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
            NSLog(@"View done dismissing");
        }];
    }
}];
```

That way, it'll wait until it's done presenting to dismiss.  You would also need to handle the case that the error happens after the animation is done (for instance, a slow connection that eventually fails), but that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: +1. But why is he trying to present and dismiss one after the other??? Is he trying to flash people with his VC? I can imagine a lawsuit on the way claiming his app causes epileptic fits :)

Comment: But, when I put a sleep between the two calls (thus blocking the UIThread) the completion block of `presentViewControllerAnimated:completion:` is also not called. So I was thinking that the completion was actually run on the UIThread..?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing because of my code example. I have edited the post to point out it actually is a simplified code example because the original is much bigger. The code I have given simulates a use-case where a network communication error might trigger a view to popup whilst another view is also being popped-up at the same time - I tried to keep it simple, quess I failed in that..:(

Comment: @MhaW ok, I edited the answer, maybe this will help you...I'm still not quite sure what you want though.

Comment: I think I'll do something like this. Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you dismiss it when its done loading?

```
[self presentViewController:changeLocationViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"View done presenting");

    NSLog(@"Dismissing view");

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"View done dismissing");
     }];
}];
```

Comment: bwahaha I beat you by 7 seconds :-)

Answer (score 0):

OK. It seems like you want to present a VC, but if there is no network found, close the VC. The only reason that I can think of needing to do it this way is if the network only gets checked in the new VC that you are presenting (and want to dismiss if it fails to connect).

**And you would be able to achieve that by implementing the code shown in the answer given by @aopsfan.**

But think about that UI flow. You are telling a starving man (the user) he can have a sandwich (the next VC that he wants to see)... But WAIT! (dismiss the wanted VC) No, you can't have the sandwich (no network)! Fooled you!.

The way to do it to keep the UI flow nice and not aggravating, would be to check for network connection before presenting the VC. Probably check for network in the IBAction (?) that you use to present the new VC. That way, you can check before presenting. Instead of present-cancel

Heck, you could even show an HUD "in progress" View to let the user know what happening!

Comment: Network connection is globally in the app. If network connection is lost, no matter where the user is in the application, the application closes whatever the user is doing and shows a 'network lost'-view

Comment: @MhaW, it makes no difference. You should still check it **before** presenting the next VC.

Comment: Hmm, I don't agree. I have a class that handles network stuff, with watchdog and all, especially so that I don't have to check network connection everywhere.. But that's another topic, haha!:)
But thanks for your thoughts and time!:)